# How to give default return value to a method that is called during a unit test? - Python

Tags: python

Here's an example class that simplifies what I have:

*class.py*

```
class MyClass(object):

    @staticmethod
    def getDictionary():
        #some calculations, returns a dictionary 

    def checkConfiguration(self):
        #some code
        self.getDictionary()
        #some other code
        return value
```

And now I am making a unit test for `checkConfiguration`:

*classTest.py*

```
import class
import unittest

class TestMyClass(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.classTest = class.MyClass() 

    def test_CheckConfiguration(self):
        #What to put here?
```

The original `CheckConfiguration` calls `getDictionary`. Is there a way to tell the `test_CheckConfiguration(self)` that if `getDictionary` is called, it should automatically return a dictionary I can type in?
Something like:

```
    def test_CheckConfiguration(self):
        if method getDictionary is called: 
            return {'a':123, 'b':22}
        checkValue = self.classTest.checkConfiguration()
```

I know this is possible in Java, though I don't have enough experience in that nor this.
Thank you.

Comment: `classTest` is local to `setUp()`. I think you mean `self.classTest = class.MyClass()`.

Comment: Yes, I did. I'll change it now :)

Comment: Since `getDictionary` is a static method you should use `MyClass.getDictionary` instead of `self.getDictionary` to make your code clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need a mocking framework.  I suggest [PyMock](http://theblobshop.com/pymock/).

Here's how you could use it:

*classTest.py*

```
import class
import pymock
import unittest

class TestMyClass(pymock.PyMockTestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.classTest = class.MyClass() 

    def test_CheckConfiguration(self):
        self.override(self.classTest, 'getDictionary')
        pymock.expectAndReturn(self.classTest.getDictionary(), {'a':123, 'b':22})
        self.replay()
        checkValue = self.classTest.checkConfiguration()
        self.verify()
```

Comment: Yup, that's what I was looking for, the word 'mocking'. I'm going to try to use the unittest.mock library that comes with Python and hopefully that'll work well :)

Answer (score 1):

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/comp.lang.python/WBhc1xAc8Hw suggests subclassing your class under test and overriding `__getattribute__` to record each call in whatever manner you need.  Not sure what else would work...